# Is it possible to start a VM group from the command line?

Tags: virtualbox

At the moment I'm using Oracle Virtualbox 4.3.30.
Previously, I was starting VMs using `VBoxHeadless --startvm <VM>` for each one of the VMs in the group I usually need for development. Which gets old. I defined aliases, but still. They're all in the same group, and I want to start them all at once (headlessly).

The group is named `work-devel`. Unfortunately, just using `VBoxHeadless --startvm /work-devel` or `VBoxHeadless --startvm work-devel` isn't doing it, and there doesn't seem to be any helpful information anywhere ([including the manual](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch08.html)). Does this functionality exist, or is it just something I really, really want to exist? I know there's no technical reason why it couldn't, and I can start multiple VMs at once in the GUI by selecting them via <kbd>Shift</kbd> + click.

Answer (score 1):

You can open the group in the virtualbox VM tree
Right-click the intended VM
and choose: "Create Shortcut in the desktop"

---

it will launch the VM using the GUID...
This way you can have VM(s) with the same name in different groups

---

Like VM "Windows10" in group "Testing" and in group "Deploy"

Comment: On my machine (running oracle virtualbox 5.0.14 on OS X) that creates separate icons for each VM in the group, rather than one for the entire group. Not downvoting because what you're suggesting may work for some version of virtualbox, just not the one I'm using.